# sqlite3.Connection class inheritance, commit not working

Tags: python, database, inheritance, sqlite

This is my first time using sqlite3 through class inheritance, and I've run into a problem where I get no traceback errors, but the queries I execute won't commit. I simplified my code

```
import sqlite3 as lite

class BaseModel(lite.Connection):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        lite.Connection.__init__(self, **args)  
        self.cur = self.cursor()

    def execute(self, query):
        self.cur.execute(query)




class Model(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        BaseModel.__init__(self, **args)

    def _new_(self):
        queries = []        
        queries.append(' '.join(['CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb1',
                         '(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,',
                         'column1 TEXT,', 
                         'column2 INT)']))

        for q in queries:
            self.execute(q) # execute the queries

        self.commit()   # write changes to db   

    def tables(self):
        query = 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" ORDER BY name' 
        results = self.execute(query) 
        return results#.fetchall()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = Model(database='test.db')
    model._new_()

    # Test Fails because the queries aren't being saved in the db
    # see Model.__new__ for details

    tables = model.tables() # get all tables

    print 'Tables Created:'

    if tables:
        for t in model.tables(): 
            print '\t%s' % str(t[0])
    else: print tables
```

Comment: Normally, it is `__new__`, not `_new_`, but I suspect that was intentional. That makes your code rather confusing to parse.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really but any thought in that.

Comment: See [Basic Customization](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization), but I think you really do not want or need to use `__new__` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *call* `self.commit()`:

```
self.commit() # write changes to db
```

Without the `()` you are merely *referencing* the method, not invoking it.

Next, your `execute()` function doesn't return anything:

```
def execute(self, query):
    return self.cur.execute(query)
```

Comment: haha, Thanks I totality missed that. I guess sometimes you need someone to point out the obvious.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but the code dosn't seem to behave any different.